# Importing online docs into SkyDrive

Tags: import, upload, onedrive

I hate to download-upload. It is stupid. The acceptable approach is the one we have to insert images into SE posts: there is an option to choose between "from my computer" and URL. Now, I want to know how to import documents into SkyDrive by URL. [I have already created the same question for Google Docs.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44673/how-to-upload-a-file-into-google-docs-given-a-url)